# Tkinter Entry Box 2 is receiving entry box 1 's characters whiles i type in entrybox 1

Tags: python, tkinter

When I type in entrybox1 it automatically appears in entrybox2. So is like anything that happens entrybox1 happens to entrybox2.

Below is my code

```
from Tkinter import*
import random

class Love:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Love Calculator")
        window.geometry("300x180")

        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()
        self.lbl = Label(frame1, text = "Love is Pure",fg="white",bg = "blue")
        self.lbl2=Label(frame1, text ="are you meant for one another",fg="White",bg = "red")
        self.lbl3=Label(frame1,text="Let FIND OUT!!",fg="white",bg = "green")
        self.lbl.pack()
        self.lbl2.pack()
        self.lbl3.pack()




        frame2=Frame(window)
        frame2.pack()
        label = Label(frame2,text = "Your Name")
        label2 = Label(frame2, text= "Your Lovers name")

        self.msg = StringVar
        entry1 = Entry(frame2, textvariable =self.msg)

        self.out = StringVar
        entry2 = Entry(frame2, textvariable =self.out)

        btCalculate=Button(frame2, text="Calculate", command=self.processButton)

        label.grid(row=1,column=1)
        label2.grid(row=2,column=1)
        entry1.grid(row=1,column=2)
        entry2.grid(row=2,column=2)
        btCalculate.grid(row=4,column=3,sticky=E)
```

Comment: Can not reproduce. However, my guess is that those two `Entry`s are using _the same_ `textvariable`. (Indeed yours _are_ the same, since they both refer to the `StringVar` class instead of creating two instances)

Answer (score 2):

Both of your Entry widgets are effectively using the same textvariable. This is because you are using `StringVar` wrong.  You aren't creating new`StringVar`s, you're merely referencing the class.

In short, you need to do this:

```
self.msg = StringVar()
```

... Rather than this:

```
self.msg = StringVar
```

Notice the use of `()`.

Comment: Thank you very much Bryan, i hope i get to get more help from you.

Comment: +1 With Python 2.7 I can indeed reproduce the problem (but neither with 2.6 nor 3.4), but could you please explain how passing the class actually works and results in both having the same variable? I could imagine that passing a callable results in that callable being called, but that should give two separate variables.

Comment: @tobias_k: under the hood, the textvariable is just a string. When you pass in a callable (or anything else), what really gets associated with the widget is `str(whatever)`. When you pass the class name, the underline tk code is given `"<Tkinter.StringVar>"` in both cases, so tk thinks they are the same textvariable.